# Looping through consecutive columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, matrix, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am trying to loop through a dataframe of columns, and the calculated result is deposited into a matrix.

The scenario can be replicated with the following sample data:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE))) # the columns to be calculated on

M1 = as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)) # a matrix to hold the results.
rownames(M1) = colnames(df)
colnames(M1) = colnames(df)
```

And appear as follows:

```
> df # Frame with columns of data, X1 to X10

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1 19  2  6  6  5  0  2  5  10
2  16  7 14 16 16 18 11  2 18  11
3   7  6 11  4  4  1 18 11 10  16
4  20  2  4 20  4  6 10  5 16   7
5   9  8 16 19 11  2 14  7 13   7
6   5 16  6  8 20 15  5 11  4   0
7  11 16 12  8 18 20 20 20 10  14
8  17 14 10  4  3 10 13 11  5   1
9   9 20 10  5  1  7 12 10  5   6
10  8 14  3 14 20 10 17 20  9  14

> M1 # Output frame to hold results

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
X1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X5   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

In `df` columns X1 and X2 are in put to the calculation, then X1 and X3, then X1 and X4, etc. Then the loop will cycle X2 and X3, then X2 and X4, etc.

Columns *n* and *m* are entered into the calculation/loop and the result should be placed into the appropriate place in the matrix that corresponds to column *n* x *m*.  The calculation itself simplLY determines the area between Xn and Xm as plotted lines. I'm not sure how to correctly construct the loop to do this:

```
  # The first iteration of the calculation, column X1 and X2 (X1 and X1 would = 0)

  y = seq(1,10,1)
  f1 = approxfun(y, df[,1] - df[,2]) # takes two columns as inputs
  f2 = function(x) abs(f1(x))

  area1 = integrate(f2, 1, 10, subdivisions = 500)
  M1[2,1] = area1$value
```

The resultant frame would produce a "half-matrix" (that is all that is needed as the mirrored half would be identical):

```
> M1
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
X1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X2   A  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X3   A  A  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X4   A  A  A  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
X5   A  A  A  A  0  0  0  0  0   0
X6   A  A  A  A  A  0  0  0  0   0
X7   A  A  A  A  A  A  0  0  0   0
X8   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  0  0   0
X9   A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  0   0
X10  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A   0
```

I began constructing a for loop but I'm tripping up on using i and j to keep X1 in until it has cycled through X2-X10, then moving on to X2, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: When I try to run `f1 = approxfun(y, df[,1] - df[,2])`, I get: `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : object 'y' not found`. Are the functions f1 and f2 the actual functions you are trying to run on your data?

Comment: Can you provide the actual calculated output maybe for just a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: @biomiha Apologies, I left the details of 'y' out of my explanation and also amended the calculation as such.  This was supposed to be a scaled down version of the original for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get your functions to work. So with the use of a random replacement function,this loop works for me:

```
area=list()  # because the actual function doesn't work
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    if(i==j){M[i,i]=0;next}
    selection=df[,c(i,j)]
    #area=integrate(f2, 1, 200, subdivisions = 500)
    area$value=mean(colSums(selection)) # something random to check
    M[i,j]=area$value
    M[j,i]=area$value
  }
}
```

But looping is generally not the most efficient way of doing things. Therefore, you might actually prefer this option:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE))) # the columns to be calculated on
my.f = function(x) abs(x[,1]-x[,2])

#y = t(as.matrix(combn(ncol(df), 2L, function(y) integrate(my.f(df[y]), 1, 200, subdivisions = 500),simplify=F))) # This doesn't work, but should be close to what you want to do

y = t(as.matrix(combn(ncol(df), 2L, function(y) mean(f(df[y]),simplify=F)))) # this works, but is just an example

N = seq_len(ncol(y))
nams = colnames(df)
M = matrix(ncol = length(nams), nrow = length(nams))
M[lower.tri(M)] = y
M = t(out)
M[lower.tri(M)] = y
M = t(M)
diag(M) = 0
rownames(M) = colnames(out) = colnames(df)
M

    X1  X2   X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8   X9 X10
X1  0.0 8.6  6.4 8.8 7.1 6.6 7.0 4.0  7.0 3.7
X2  8.6 0.0  5.0 4.4 5.5 5.4 4.4 9.2  8.0 7.7
X3  6.4 5.0  0.0 7.2 5.9 5.8 7.6 7.0 10.4 6.5
X4  8.8 4.4  7.2 0.0 5.9 4.4 5.4 9.6  8.4 7.3
X5  7.1 5.5  5.9 5.9 0.0 7.3 5.3 9.1  8.5 8.0
X6  6.6 5.4  5.8 4.4 7.3 0.0 6.0 8.4  5.6 3.7
X7  7.0 4.4  7.6 5.4 5.3 6.0 0.0 8.8  4.4 5.7
X8  4.0 9.2  7.0 9.6 9.1 8.4 8.8 0.0  9.6 6.9
X9  7.0 8.0 10.4 8.4 8.5 5.6 4.4 9.6  0.0 5.5
X10 3.7 7.7  6.5 7.3 8.0 3.7 5.7 6.9  5.5 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for multiple solutions @Wave, I'm only now getting an opportunity to try and implement this so I will come back with results.  As I mentioned in a comment above, I had left something out of the calculation, which I have edited in the original question, my apologies.

Comment: I was able to implement your first suggestion on my original data and function, with a 3x3 sample, this worked well, thanks!  I'm trying the second suggestion given it appears to be more efficient (and my intended application will be 100x100 and greater).  How might I adapt the `y = t...` line of code for my original data which is decimal values? I assume the `2L` relates to the sample which is integers. Thanks.

Comment: You only have to change the function. 2L refers to the number of elements to choose (2 columns), and shouldn't be changed for your example.